# Transitive, Intransitive Verbs and Particles

Tags: particles, transitivity

I think that these sentences are both correct:

> 旅行の日程**が決められました**。

and

> 旅行の日程**が決まりました**。

But if I use

> 旅行の日程**を決まりました**。

is this correct?

Comment: 決まる is intransitive, therefore it can never be used with the particle を

Answer (score 1):

旅行の日程が決まりました is correct and natural.

旅行の日程が決められました is not grammatically mistaken, but unnatural (hardly heard).

旅行の日程を決まりました is grammatically wrong, sounds weird.